# Understanding WEKA for Dummies – My Woes with WEKA

Tags: weka

I have an assignment I am working on that uses WEKA and Google’s OpenRefine.

I am trying to understand it so I can best utilise the dataset’s metadata to produce a report that uses Classification, Regression, Association and Clustering algorithms.

I can run through the spreadsheet I have to work with and amend the dirty data using OpenRefine, but I simply don’t understand where to go next after I pass the clean data into WEKA.

> Example: I try to use the Explorer in WEKA to take the spreadsheet
> that I’ve converted into an arff file and run the OneR – B6
> classifier, but the visualisation looks clunky.
>
> I have also tried the method where I use J48 tree classifier, but the
> tree is just a mess, and I don’t know what to do.

TL;DR – I need help to understand WEKA visualisation using Classification, Regression, Association and Clustering algorithms.